# What is this action called and how is it called : popup shows content of second sheet in spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, libreoffice

[Reduced Excel Spreadsheet - Curiosity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z415fbnakz51tfc/Curiosity.xlsx?dl=0) When clicking on cell B6 ( or 6 thru 11 ) , a disclosure caret shows and a popup is presented with the contents from a second sheet. It's not a pivot table, VLOOKUP is close. I don't know what it is called, so I can not research it further. All I need is a starting point. Thanks. Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, "Data Validation" has been used:

1. Select the range you want to have the desired behavior
2. From the "Data" Tab, Choose "Data Validation"
   [image]
3. See [Full Description](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2)

Similar behavior is achievable in "Developer Mode" as well:

1. First Enable the Developer Tab from "File->Options->Customize Ribbon"
   [image]
2. Put into "Design Mode"
3. Add  Appropriate control (e.g.: Combo-box) via "Insert" button.
4. [Complete documentation is available here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-use-the-forms-controls-on-a-worksheet-in-excel-e7e33c0c-f080-4443-b565-d21b1bdbcf43)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. After a wee bit of fiddling, got it to work perfectly. Thank you F.I.V.